Kafka too many messages alert
I have an issue with Kafka alerts.
We're receiving alerts for KafkaTooManyMessages, the threshold is 50K messages.
When the threshold is breached, we're receiving the alerts properly, however we get a Resolve status for the alert after a few minutes (sometimes hours) but the messages count didn't decrease below the threshold and therefore the alert is firing again almost instantly.
Does someone have an idea for what is the reason that could happen?
I've tried to look at the alert config and I didn't see anything that can cause this issue.
- alert: KafkaTooManyMessagesBehind
  expr: sum by (instance, groupId, topic) (kafka_consumer_group_ConsumerLagMetrics_Value{name="SumOffsetLag", groupId!~"(?i).*stm.*"}) > 50000
  for: 1m
  labels:
    severity: Warning
  annotations:
     title: '- Warning Kafka Too Many Messages Behind (Non-Stm Groups)'
     description: |
  Kafka consumer group {{ $labels.groupId }} on topic {{ $labels.topic }} in instance {{ $labels.instance }} has more than 50,000 messages behind, current count is {{ $value }}.
     summary: Kafka consumers with more than 50k messages behind including topic name

Result from query (img)

Show your alert rule. And show results of the query in that alert rule on the period where problem is present

alert rule added.
sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean by 'show results of the query in that alert rule on the period where problem is present' - the alerts are triggered to Slack. what results can I present to you?

Take query of the alert (everything in the li e after expr:), paste it into prometheus' web console, switch to Graph tab, select time range and timestamp to moments when problem happened.

I added the query result

Looks very strange. Either you have extremely fast fluctuations of total lag values, or you have problems with continuity of the metrics. Check also results for the same query, but without >50000: are they continuous?

No
https://prnt.sc/i1pf7QGR3wSL

Yep, you have problems with continuity of the data. You'll need to investigate why: is it because target is inaccessible or because metrics in use has some specific behaviour. In any case, I doubt this will be on-topic for SO.
